# form validation with jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-validate

I am trying to write a form validation. i have to check username in database unique or not.but  it doesn't working. register.jsp my form page and deneme.jsp is checking the username is unique or not.here is pages

**register.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>

    <form name="form" id="form">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> 
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Sign up">
    </form>

    <script
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form").validate({
                rules : {
                    username : {
                        remote : {
                            url : "deneme.jsp",
                            async : false,
                            type : "post",
                            data : {
                                username : function() {
                                    return $("#username").val()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                messages : {
                    username : {
                        remote : "alredy exist"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**and here is deneme.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%
    Connection con;
    Statement stm = null;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        con = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/odevdb", "root",
                        "hawking1887/");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        stm = con.createStatement();
        rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from users where username = '"
                + username + "'");
        if (rs.next()) {
            out.print("false"); 

        } else {
            out.print("true"); 
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        out.print(e);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        out.print(e);
    }
%>
```

Comment: You've included the wrong plugin.  The **jQuery Form Validator** is not the **jQuery Validate** plugin.

Comment: The `remote` method already sends the data from the input field by default.  You do not need to use the `data` option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**You're either using the wrong plugin or the wrong code format.**

Your script includes is for the **[jQuery Form Validator plugin](http://formvalidator.net/#home)** (version 2.1.47).

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
```

However, the syntax in your `.validate()` call, the `rules` option, the `remote` method, (*and your tag,* [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate)) are all for the **[jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org)** (*currently on version 1.13.0*).

```
$("#form").validate({
   rules : {
       username : {
           remote : {
           ....
```

---

The easiest fix would be to include the correct plugin for the code you've already written...

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, you'll need to fix your code to conform to the plugin you've included.  (*There appears to be no `remote` method as part of the [jQuery Form Validator plugin](http://formvalidator.net/#home).*)

Comment: @erhanurun, which one did you fix?  The code or the plugin?  Now it's up to you to troubleshoot.  What exactly does "not working" mean?  What does your JavaScript console say?  Is the remote file being found?  Is it returning the correct response?

Comment: the error message "already exist" has to appear near the textbox

Comment: also I changed the plugin there is no problem on the plugin. there is no exception in the console but the error message can't appear

Comment: @erhanurun, for a custom message, inside your JSP function, return a JSON encoded string as the validation message instead of a `false`.  This is described in the docs:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/